# HTML <A href> link to another page does not work

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I am trying to link two pages, index.html and professors.html. They have the EXACT same code except for a different placeholders in the searchbar and obviously the different navigation links. They are also in the same folder and are linked to the same css.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <title>Group A93 Final Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navlink">
    <header>
        <nav>
             <a href="professors.html"> Search by Professor</a>
        </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container, flex-outer">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>University of Maryland class and Professor Database</h1>
                <img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/thumbs/2x/university-of-maryland-logo.png" alt="UMD Logo">
            </div>
            
            <div class = "search-bar">
                <input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Enter Course"></input>
                <button
                id="search_button" class = "search_button" name="search_button" type="submit">
                    Search
                  </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navWrapper">
                <ul class="suggestions"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

professors.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <title>Group A93 Final Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navlinke">
        <header>
            <nav>
                 <a href="index.html"> Search by Course Name</a>
            </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container, flex-outer">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Final Project</h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "search-bar">
                <input type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Enter Professor"></input>
                <button
                id="search_button" class = "search_button" name="search_button" type="submit">
                    Search
                  </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navWrapper">
                <ul class="suggestions"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
 body{
     background-color: rgb(255, 252, 104);
 }

 h1 {
    color: #2a2a2a;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 80;
  }
  nav {
 
    z-index: 5;

}

  .header > img {
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    left: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    position:absolute; 
      top:-40px; 
      left:0; 
}

 .textInput {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 10px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .search-bar > button{
    align-items: center;
    left: 955px;
    top:165px; 
    position:absolute; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;

  }

  button:hover {
    background-color: #eb2f00;
    color: white;
  }
```

The very frustrating thing is that the link works on the professors.html site but not the index.html page. I need them to work on both. The link on index.html works when I click it through the inspect element but not on the page itself. When I take away the css the link on index.html works but I obviously need the css. This is very confusing and frustrating because both htmls are the exact same but yet it does not work on the index.html. I am lost on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Problem identified: The link in the index.page is behind the image. The image is 'blocking' the cursor from accessing the link or hiding the link from access.

My suggestion would be add position:sticky and z-index:100px to the nav bar or give the link an id then assign it the above css properties.

```
/*Note: Using position:sticky on the whole navbar may alter how the navbar displays*/
nav {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1000px; /* A high z-index will ensure the link is always on top */
}
```

or

```
/* Give the link an id or class*/
#link {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1000px; /* A high z-index will ensure the link is always on top */
}
```

Play around with the position property depending on how you want the link to be placed.

*Css experts: better suggestions are welcome. I aint one yet but I have encountered that problem so many times and thats how I solve it*

Comment: No matter how large I make the z index the link is still covered up

Comment: @DimejiOlayinka Have you included position: sticky to the link?. because without position then it will still be behind